# Python: Flask-security, register does not persist user

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

Everything else is working fine, registration works and I am logged in but as soon as I log out, it says the user does not exist. I suspect it's expecting a confirm link email but these are my settings:

app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True

when I create a user by force on startup of flask, it has no problem. So I suspect this is something from flask-security settings wise, I just can't figure it out reading the documentation.

I've been stuck on this for days and I am getting worried!

Comment: Have you checked your database to see if the users are getting stored?

Comment: I am using sql lite is there a phpmyadmin sorta thing for sqlite?

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html